# Is it mandatory to disable Hbase tables before upating TTL?

Tags: hbase, alter, ttl

I have  hbase tables whose TTL I want to update..Is it mandatory to disable the tables before altering them to update TTL?

Comment: Please add your code so we can help you. Thanks!

Comment: I have TTL set for 324000 i.e 5 weeks for hbase table and I have to update it  to 2419200 i.e 4 weeks. So, I have to run this command  :  alter 'tablename', {NAME=> 'd',TTL => 2419200 }; For that do I have to run disable   'tablename' command before alter command or not. This is my question.

Comment: Read about `hbase.online.schema.update.enable` configuration